# C# how can I uncheck dynamically created radio buttons?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm dynamically creating some radio buttons in a form, and I would like users to have the ability to deselect them. Users' options should be select one, or select none(safer to use radio buttons than checkboxes). I tried using the EventHandler and creating an event, but I'm not having much luck getting it to work properly.

Here's what I've got making the buttons:

```
private void makeRadioButtons(string size, Panel pnl)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            RadioButton btn = new RadioButton();
            btn.AutoSize = true;
            btn.Name = i;
            btn.Text = i;
            btn.Location = new Point(100*i, 0);
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(radioHandler);
            pnl.Controls.Add(btn);
        }
}
```

And here is my event handler:

```
private void radioHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton rdo = sender as RadioButton;
        if(rdo.Checked)
        {
            rdo.Checked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            rdo.Checked = true;
        }
    }
```

When I compile I get the buttons, but can't select or deselect them. I feel like I'm close, but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: winforms or asp.net?

Comment: Aren't they checked automatically when they are clicked (and the others in `pnl.Controls` unchecked)? What _exactly_ do you want to do? And note that you could convert that `if` into simply setting `rdo.Checked = !rdo.Checked;`

Comment: Radio buttons are designed to enforce one and only 1 selection in a group. How is it safer to use them when this is exactly the functionality of a checkbox that you're asking for?

Comment: you dont need the event handler

Comment: I agree that you shouldn't do it like this. Most users won't even try to deselect a radio button, just because it's not in the nature of a radio button to be deselected. Either use check boxes and make sure that only one is selected at a time or add another radio button that represents the "none" choice. The latter is probably the best choice from a UX point of view.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane I want only 1 selection in a group IF a selection should be made at all. If a selection is made accidentally, I would like it to be cleared. This is not the functionality of a checkbox in the sense that I only want 1 selection to be possible.

Comment: @NicoSchertler you're right, I should go with one of these 2 options. But since I started it this way, I would like to at the very least figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Then group your checkboxes, and when one is selected loop the rest and deselect them.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane that is what I'll likely end up doing.

Comment: @DanielA.White asp.net

Answer (score 1):

RadioButtons are checked automatically by default. You can avoid that by setting their `AutoCheck` property to `false` when you create them.

Then you need to change your handler like this:

```
private void radioHandler(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rbt = (RadioButton)sender;
    if (rbt.Checked)
    {
        rbt.Checked = false;
        return;
    }

    rbt.Checked = true;
    foreach (RadioButton r in pnl.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
        if (r != rbt) r.Checked = false;
}
```

So if the clicked button was checked, it is unchecked. If it was not checked, we check it and uncheck all the others (this is necessary since we set `AutoCheck` to `false`).

Comment: This is still causing the issue that nothing is able to be checked.

Comment: I put it in my program and compiled it (using visual studio). When I run the program from VS I still can't select any radio buttons in that group. Perhaps my issue is somewhere outside of the handler?

Comment: @Chuck did you set `btn.AutoCheck = false` in your `makeRadioButtons()` method as I suggested? Yes maybe it's outside of the handler, but then I cannot help you from here :) And please try to _debug_, not just run the program. Put a break point at the start of the handler, check if it is called at all and what happens when it is executed. (to debug, start the program with F5, not Ctrl+F5).

Comment: @Chuck You just commented that it is about asp.net, not about windows forms. My answer is based completely on windows forms, so maybe it's different for asp radiobuttons

Comment: @Chuck on the other hand, if you could compile that (including `AutoCheck = false`) then you _are_ using windows forms, as the `System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton` does not have an `AutoCheck` property....

Answer (score 0):

It s your event handler code that makes the mess.

Radiobuttons are automatically checked/unchecked when user clicks.

Your code makes the opposite !

**Edit**

Just removing of the handler is needed.

Comment: You should provide some code on how it should be properly handled.